# Java Selenium getting Elements out of a Form which are Checked with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, forms, selenium, xpath

I want to select the checkboxes and check if they are checked the HTML looks like this

```
h3>Checkboxes</h3>
<form id="checkboxes">
<input type="checkbox">
checkbox 1
<br>
<input checked="" type="checkbox">
checkbox 2
</form>
</div>


h3>Checkboxes</h3>
<form id="checkboxes">
<input type="checkbox">
checkbox 1
<br>
<input checked="" type="checkbox">
checkbox 2
</form>
</div>

<script>

var form = document.getElementById('checkboxes');
var checkboxes = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i=0, len=checkboxes.length; i<len; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].onclick = function() {
      this.checked ? this.setAttribute("checked", "") : this.removeAttribute("checked");
    }
}
</script>
```

I have tried to get the elemtns out by xpath, id and tagName but nothing worked.

here is my Java code:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/ul/li[5]/a")).click();
        List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.id("checkboxes"));
```

My probelm is that the size of elements is 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the check boxes number by using the Java code written below:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "src/geckodriver");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/ul/li[5]/a")).click();

    By locator = By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']");
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(locator);
   int size = elements.size();
    System.out.println(size);
```

You can select any checkbox you want and then you can check the status of the checkbox on the web page:

**Code Snippet for checking the status of the checkboxes**

```
for(int i=0; i<elements.size();i++){
        String check_state= elements.get(i).getAttribute("checked");
        if(check_state == null){
            System.out.println("Checbox "+(i+1)+" is not selected");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you really much it works.  Can you please tell me, where i can learn more about the xpath you used //input[@type='checkbox']  cause im always unsure which path i should use.